# How to limit connections to glassfish4?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, servlet-filters, glassfish-4

I'm running a web application on a glassfish 4 server. The web application should not be accessible for all of connection. 
I want to limit 100 connections. if the 101th connection comes, the web application will show serverbusy.jsp.

**My question:**

**Solution 1:** 
How to configure Glassfish to limit connections.

**Solution 2:**
Can i use jsp (Application Implicit object to count connection)?

Answer (score 0):

The first thought that comes to my mind is that you can expose current connection count property through JMX and then write a filter that will perform a redirect after checking this property